# How to use map inside map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dictionary

Here is my data and col {array of objects}

```js
let columns = [
    {
      text: "Id",
      dataField: "UserId",
    },
    { text: "Name", dataField: "Name" },
    {
      text: "Gender",
      dataField: "Gender",
      },
    { text: "age", dataField: "age" },
  ];
```

```js
let data = [
    { id: 1, name: "Manik", age: 20, Gender: "male" },
    { id: 2, name: "harsha", age: 22, Gender: "female" },
    { id: 3, name: "robert", age: 18, Gender: "male" },
    { id: 4, name: "John", age: 24, Gender: "female" },
  ];
```

Here is my map inside the map function.

```js
 {columns.map(column =>
        {return data.map((data, i) => {
return(
<div>{data.column.dataField}</div>
)
```

I want to access an object output attached to another object like `data.column.data field`.Here `column.data field` should return output and in turn, it should be bound to data.Is it possible or any changes to be done?

> but this code is returning this error

```
Parsing error: Identifier expected.eslint
```

Comment: Missing some `)` and `}` at the end?

Comment: To use a string as a property name, you can use this syntax: `data[column.dataField]` but you'll have to change the `dataField` values to be the same as the property names of the objects inside `data` (`id` instead of `UserId`, `name` instead of `Name`, etc.).

Comment: I think you want `data[column.dataField]` instead of `data.column.dataField`. Not mentioning the dataFields don't match the actual fields of the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution:

```
// e.g. [
//   [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
//   [ 'Manik', 'harsha', 'robert', 'John', ],
//   [ 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', ],
//   [ 20, 22, 18, 24 ],
// ]
columns.map((column) => {

    // list of "one column of each data item", e.g. ids: [ 1, 2, 3, ... ] 
    return data.map( ( dataItem, i ) => {
        return (
            dataItem[ column.dataField ]
            //<div>{dataItem[ column.dataField ]}</div>
        );
    } );
});
```

*(this assumes that the `dataField` property holds the `data` key to use, but then they also have to be made consistent. See comments to your question.)*